# returns an array of objects that contains the product names

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am working on a javascript snippet for Google tag manager where i have to display the output like below.

`[{"product1":"Protein Corn Muffin"},{"product2":"Salted Caramel Super Smoothie"},{"product3":"Pop Corn"},{"product4":"Fruit Pops!"}]`

Attached datalayer.

```
dataLayer = {
  products: [
    {
      name: "Protein Corn Muffin",
      id: "SHOP - US - 6032011P",
      price: "5.95",
      quantity: 1,
    },
    {
      name: "Salted Caramel Super Smoothie",
      id: "SHOP - US - 6021050P",
      price: "7.95",
      quantity: 3,
    },
    {
      name: "Pop Corn",
      id: "SHOP - US - 4117050P",
      price: "8.95",
      quantity: 2,
    },
    {
      name: "Fruit Pops!",
      id: "SHOP - US - 41441109P",
      price: "9.99",
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
};
```

```
Can anyone guide me.
```

Comment: Please check array map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Solves your thing but please do some research next time.

```
datalayer.products.map( (p, i) => ({[`product${i+1}`]: p.name }))
```

Comment: just marking:  datalayer.product should be datalayer.products, missing s

Answer (score 0):

Another traditional solution:

```
var prods=[];
for(var i=0;i<dataLayer.products.length;i++){
   prods.push({['product'+(i+1)]: dataLayer.products[i].name});
}
```

---

**Working Code**

```js
var dataLayer = {
  products: [{
      name: "Protein Corn Muffin",
      id: "SHOP - US - 6032011P",
      price: "5.95",
      quantity: 1,
    },
    {
      name: "Salted Caramel Super Smoothie",
      id: "SHOP - US - 6021050P",
      price: "7.95",
      quantity: 3,
    },
    {
      name: "Pop Corn",
      id: "SHOP - US - 4117050P",
      price: "8.95",
      quantity: 2,
    },
    {
      name: "Fruit Pops!",
      id: "SHOP - US - 41441109P",
      price: "9.99",
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
};


var prods = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dataLayer.products.length; i++) {
  prods.push({
    ['product' + (i + 1)]: dataLayer.products[i].name
  });
}

console.log(prods)
```